# Problema ao calcular média de uma grade com numeros vazios

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Tenho um *StringGrid1* que preencho os dados e apartir disso eu calculo o total e a média. Na imagem 1, demonstro funcionando corretamente. Porém eu posso não querer colocar um número em uma das células, o que causa o erro da imagem 2.

[image: Imagens]

O código que estou usando:

```
procedure TForm2.Calcular(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SaveStringGrid(StringGrid1, 'c:\temp.txt');
end;


procedure SaveStringGrid(StringGrid: TStringGrid; const FileName: TFileName);
var
  f:    TextFile;
  i, k, sum: Integer;
  med: EXTENDED;
begin
  with StringGrid do
  begin
    for i := 1 to RowCount-1 do
    begin
      sum := 0;
      med := 0;

      for k := 1 to ColCount-3 do
        begin
          sum :=sum + strtoint(Cells [k, i]);
          med := sum / k;
          Cells [ColCount -2, i] := inttostr(sum);
          Cells [ColCount -1, i] := FloatToStr(med);
        end;
    end;
  en
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [função `strtoint`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=strtoint) pode lançar uma exceção se a string dada não tiver um formato numérico.

Assim sendo, no lugar disso:

```
          sum :=sum + strtoint(Cells [k, i]);
```

Use isso:

```
          try
            sum := sum + strtoint(Cells[k, i]);
          on Exception : EConvertError do
            // Ignora a exceção
          end;
```

Isso daí vai fazer ele ignorar quaisquer células com formatos não-numéricos. Se quiser ignorar apenas as que estiverem em branco, então use simplesmente isso:

```
          if Cells[k, i] <> '' then
            sum := sum + strtoint(Cells[k, i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o sistema de tratamento de erros que o @Victor Stafusa sugeriu, ou ainda pode usar uma variação da função que ja usa, que é a `StrToInt`:

ao invés de:

```
sum :=sum + strtoint(Cells [k, i]);
```

usar:

```
sum :=sum + StrToIntDef(Cells [k, i], 0);
```

`StrToIntDef` tenta converter e assume o valor que foi definido depois da vírgula.

Existe outras como `StrToFloatDef`, `StrToDateTimeDef` etc. Ver mais detalhes na `System.SysUtils`